# Function call + compute the return value + compare the computed value in C

Tags: c, unix, if-statement

Apologize for ambiguous title but I simply did not know how else to put it.

Anyway, I want a piece of code to do the same thing this does in one line (in an if statement)

```
ret= fee(XYZ);
if((fii(ret) && foh(ret)) !=0)
{
  //do something
}
```

like put all that into something like

```
if(_______FUM________)    
{
  //do the same thing
 }
```

Is there anything I can do for this? The answer is probably staring at me in my face. But I am stuck here.

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Are you paying for code storage by the newline?

Comment: No. I'm actually editing a piece of code that has a lot of if-else statements and would need a lot more editing if I used up two lines.

Comment: Perhaps the better solution to that problem would be to refactor the code so that it's not copy-pasta as much?

Comment: It's not so much copy-pasting as it is editing many files of similar code with the same mistake. Rewriting the code is, like I said, more time consuming at the moment and would need a lot of editing in a lot of places. And it's not my code I'm editing. I was just looking for a simplest solution for the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [comma operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma_operator):

```
if(ret = fee(XYZ), (fii(ret) && foh(ret)) !=0)
```

But why?!

(Also, the `!=0` appears to be redundant.)

Comment: And the 0 part was a bad example because I'm not checking for !=0  but actually a defined macro.